# Click on a button and get it's Ancestor Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the **form tag** when I click on it's **descendant button**.
And when I click on another **button** then catch it's **ancestor** form tag only.

What will be the jquery code?

**My HTML Code is here

```html
<form class="edit">
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
    <!-- When I click this button I want it's ancestor form tag only the edit form not the next or more-->
      <span><button>Click</button></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form
<form class="edit">
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
    <!-- When I click this button I want it's ancestor form tag only the edit form not the next, previous, or more..-->
      <span><button>Click</button></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form
```

Comment: where is your javascript code?

Comment: I want the javascript code for solution.

Comment: Ah, you think stackoverflow is a Code writing service?

Comment: A simple look through traversal methods in jQuery api would answer this for yourself. There is a whole section in API for *"Traversing"* and examples are given for all methods

Comment: Can you give me the specific answer?